# Groupby por varias columnas y sumar los valores string de una de ellas

Tags: python, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe con varias columnas:

```
      Precio Combustible  Año_del_vehiculo  Caballos Comunidad_autonoma  \
0         950      Diésel            2000.0     110.0            Navarra   
1        6200    Gasolina            2017.0      82.0     Islas Canarias   
2       11490    Gasolina            2016.0     130.0             Madrid   
3       28500      Diésel            2017.0     150.0     Islas Baleares   
4        8200      Diésel            2012.0     150.0           Cataluña   
...       ...         ...               ...       ...                ...   
47260   18490    Gasolina            2018.0     140.0          Andalucia   
47261   14500      Diésel            2015.0     150.0          Andalucia   
47262   11000    Gasolina            2019.0      72.0          Andalucia   
47263   47900    Gasolina            2013.0     450.0            Galicia   
47264    2790      Diésel            2006.0      70.0           Cataluña   

                   Marca_y_Modelo Año_Venta Mes_Venta  
0                     SEAT Toledo      2020        12  
1                      CITROEN C1      2021        01  
2                    PEUGEOT 3008      2021        01  
3      LAND-ROVER Discovery Sport      2021        01  
4                     HONDA Civic      2020        12  
...                           ...       ...       ...  
47260                 HYUNDAI i30      2020        11  
47261              RENAULT Laguna      2021        01  
47262                 PEUGEOT 108      2021        01  
47263                    AUDI RS4      2021        01  
47264                  CITROEN C2      2021        01
```

Necesito agrupar por varias columnas y que cuente el numero de valores de la columna de combustible.

que las columnas muestren, su comunidad, año,mes,  y ahí la suma por tipos de combustible:
un ejemplo: La suma de los combustibles que se han vendido en madrid en septiembre 2022

Necesito algo así:

```
           
comunidad autonoma        año      mes           gasolina     diesel       hibrido        
madrid                2021      agosto           100          40.......
andalucia             2020      septiembre       50           50...........................
castilla               2020       abril           70           60.......
galicia               20222       marzo           80           80.........
```

las demas columnas no las necesito.

He probado varias cosas:

```
coches_usados['Cuenta'] = coches_usados.groupby(['Comunidad_autonoma','Año_Venta','Mes_Venta','Combustible'])['Cuenta'].transform('count')

df.set_index(['Comunidad_autonoma','Año_Venta','Mes_Venta','Combustible','Cuenta'])
```

sin resultado.

también he intentado:

```
coches_usados2=coches_usados.groupby(['Comunidad_autonoma',"Año_Venta", "Mes_Venta",'Combustible'])[['Combustible']].aggregate(['count'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo puedes hacer con [`pandas.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html).

El problema al agregar la cuenta de los tipos de combustible es que estás utilizando mal [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) (Te recomiendo repasar la documentación). Para el ejemplo voy a utilizar `agg` que es un alias de `aggregate`, yo lo uso por conveniencia porque es más corto.

Utilizando los datos que pusiste en tu pregunta en un `dataframe` de prueba desde un archivo "sample.csv"

```
   Precio Combustible  Año_del_vehiculo  Caballos Comunidad_autonoma  \
0     950      Diésel            2000.0     110.0            Navarra   
1    6200    Gasolina            2017.0      82.0     Islas Canarias   
2   11490    Gasolina            2016.0     130.0             Madrid   
3   28500      Diésel            2017.0     150.0     Islas Baleares   
4    8200      Diésel            2012.0     150.0           Cataluña   
5   18490    Gasolina            2018.0     140.0          Andalucia   
6   14500      Diésel            2015.0     150.0          Andalucia   
7   11000    Gasolina            2019.0      72.0          Andalucia   
8   47900    Gasolina            2013.0     450.0            Galicia   
9    2790      Diésel            2006.0      70.0           Cataluña   

               Marca_y_Modelo  Año_Venta  Mes_Venta  
0                 SEAT Toledo       2020         12  
1                  CITROEN C1       2021          1  
2                PEUGEOT 3008       2021          1  
3  LAND-ROVER Discovery Sport       2021          1  
4                 HONDA Civic       2020         12  
5                 HYUNDAI i30       2020         11  
6              RENAULT Laguna       2021          1  
7                 PEUGEOT 108       2021          1  
8                    AUDI RS4       2021          1  
9                  CITROEN C2       2021          1
```

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df1 = df.groupby(['Comunidad_autonoma','Año_Venta','Mes_Venta','Combustible']).agg({'Combustible': 'count'}).unstack(3).droplevel(0, axis = 1).reset_index()
df1.columns = df1.columns.rename('')
print(df1)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
  Comunidad_autonoma  Año_Venta  Mes_Venta  Diésel  Gasolina
0          Andalucia       2020         11     NaN       1.0
1          Andalucia       2021          1     1.0       1.0
2           Cataluña       2020         12     1.0       NaN
3           Cataluña       2021          1     1.0       NaN
4            Galicia       2021          1     NaN       1.0
5     Islas Baleares       2021          1     1.0       NaN
6     Islas Canarias       2021          1     NaN       1.0
7             Madrid       2021          1     NaN       1.0
8            Navarra       2020         12     1.0       NaN
```

Explicación:

1. Agrupamos utilizando todas las columnas necesarias:

```
df.groupby(['Comunidad_autonoma','Año_Venta','Mes_Venta','Combustible'])
```

2. Agregamos la cuenta de cada tipo de combustible. El formato es un diccionario con el nombre de la columna y la función:

```
.agg({'Combustible': 'count'})
```

3. Hacemos `unstack` del multi índice 3, los multi índice se enumeran empezando por `0` de izquierda a derecha, por lo que 'Comunidad_autonoma' = 0, 'Año_Venta' = 1, 'Mes_Venta' = 2, 'Combustible' = 3:

```
.unstack(3)
```

**Nota:** Si lo dejáramos hasta aquí se crearían dos niveles de columnas ya que tanto Diésel como Gasolina se crearon a partir de la columna "Combustible", de esta forma:

```
                                            Combustible         
Combustible                                 Diésel Gasolina
Comunidad_autonoma Año_Venta Mes_Venta                     
Andalucia          2020      11                NaN      1.0
                   2021      1                 1.0      1.0
Cataluña           2020      12                1.0      NaN
                   2021      1                 1.0      NaN
Galicia            2021      1                 NaN      1.0
Islas Baleares     2021      1                 1.0      NaN
Islas Canarias     2021      1                 NaN      1.0
Madrid             2021      1                 NaN      1.0
Navarra            2020      12                1.0      NaN
```

4. Eliminamos uno de los niveles de columnas, los multi niveles de columna se enumeran empezando por `0` de arriba hacia abajo:

```
.droplevel(0, axis = 1)
```

**Nota:** Si lo dejamos hasta aquí todavía vamos a tener un multi índice con las siguientes columnas 'Comunidad_autonoma','Año_Venta','Mes_Venta'

5. Hacemos `reset_index` para quitar el multi índice:

```
.reset_index()
```

6. Por último, podemos ver que la fila donde están las columnas dice "Combustible" al inicio, este sería el nombre de la fila de las columnas, lo podemos quitar de la siguiente forma:

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.rename('')
```

Comment: Genial muchas gracias, estoy aprendiendo un montón con tus respuestas.

Comment: No hay de que, algo que me ha servido mucho a mi es leer las preguntas anteriores de otros usuarios, aunque ya estén resueltas e intentar resolverlo. Saludos!